# Como poder hacer la union de varias columnas,de diferentes tablas para formar una tabla en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero saber,como puedo unir 2 tablas con datos y columnas totalmente diferentes entre si para formar una tabla nueva con la union de sus columnas.

Ejemplos;

De la tabla tProducto quiero la columna cNombreProducto(los datos que estan hay son de ingresados de excel a sql server):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La otra tabla que es tPregunta quiero los datos de la columna cTextoPregunta(Que los datos son de un archivo pasado de excel a sql server):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer esa union de esas 2 columnas y formas la tabla nueva con eso?

Comment: ¿La fecha que quieres agregar es siempre la misma?

Comment: Si es la misma pero la fecha es un ejemplo de prueba.Los datos no son lo importante lo que quiero saber es, como puedo unir esa columna a otra para la nueva tabla que quiero crear? y muchas gracias se puedes responder mi duda.

Comment: ¿cómo se relaciona la tabla1 y la tabla2? ¿Por qué una nueva tabla y no una vista?

Comment: Planteado así es confuso y no recomendable. ¿Estas seguro de que la fila1 de la primera tabla debe tener como valor la fila1 de la segunda tabla? ¿Los datos casan de esa manera? ¿Y si se elimina algun dato de algunas de las tablas? Te cargarias la relación... ¿Existe en la tabla2 alguna clave foranea que haga referencia la tabla1? En ese caso puedes usar JOIN. Lo que planteas sin ningun tipo de relación entre las tablas es inconsistente y amenaza la integridad de tu BBDD

Comment: Se que tiene que tener la mismo tipo de variable para la union pero quiero saber si se puede es unir esa columna a para tener la de fecha como la columna 3 de la nueva tabla. Se puede?

Comment: La respuesta general es: si se puede. A tu pregunta le falta más información para poder ser respondida. Sugiero que añadas un caso de uso. Si no tienes uno, inventalo, para hablar sobre un problema concreto que tenga una solución específica.

Comment: También, responde las preguntas que se te hacen en comentarios. Sigo esperando respuesta de las preguntas que te hice antes.

Comment: El tema es: si siempre es un mismo valor el que quieres agregar en una nueva columnas o efectivamente es una tabla secundaria con valores distintos. Lo primero es sencillo, lo segundo siempre tienen que hacerse con algún un criterio que relacione ambas tablas, si no indicas este criterio, es difícil poder ayudarte, como ya te han comentado.

Comment: Por supuesto que los datos son importantes, porque de esa forma podemos saber si lo que quieres en específico es posible o no. En este caso, lo que quieres sí es posible...con otros datos puede ser que no

Comment: estimado en su pregunta mostró dos tablas, considerando esas dos tablas agregue una tercera que sería el resultado que espera obtener,  de esa forma se entenderá mejor lo que está preguntando

Comment: Hola puedes poner la informacion de las tablas? nombres, campos y etc para poder responder? gracias!

Comment: En palabras simples, ¿lo que quieres es una tabla con la permutación de todos los productos y todas las preguntas? Y ¿esa tabla la quieres de-normalizada (es decir, las descripciones de los productos y el texto de las preguntas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La unión es posible. Supongamos los siguientes datos:

```
create table productos
(
id_producto int,
nombre varchar(32)
)

create table preguntas
(
id_pregunta int,
pregunta varchar(32)
)

insert into productos values (1, 'Cervezas')
insert into productos values (2, 'Pañales')
insert into productos values (3, 'Gaseosas')
insert into productos values (4, 'Lacteos')
insert into productos values (5, 'Harinas')

insert into preguntas values (1, 'Le gusta la opcion 1 o 2?')
insert into preguntas values (2, 'Le gusta menos o mas?')
insert into preguntas values (3, 'Que marca le gusta?')
insert into preguntas values (4, 'Le gusta la opcion 3 o 4?')
insert into preguntas values (5, 'Cual es su sabor favorito')
```

El problema de unir las tablas sin un criterio, es que tenemos como resultado el *producto cartesiano* de ambas:

```
select nombre, pregunta
from productos, preguntas
```

Este es el resultado:

```
nombre                           pregunta                         
-------------------------------- -------------------------------- 
Cervezas                         Le gusta la opcion 1 o 2?        
Cervezas                         Le gusta menos o mas?            
Cervezas                         Que marca le gusta?              
Cervezas                         Le gusta la opcion 3 o 4?        
Cervezas                         Cual es su sabor favorito        
Pañales                          Le gusta la opcion 1 o 2?        
Pañales                          Le gusta menos o mas?            
Pañales                          Que marca le gusta?              
Pañales                          Le gusta la opcion 3 o 4?        
Pañales                          Cual es su sabor favorito        
Gaseosas                         Le gusta la opcion 1 o 2?        
Gaseosas                         Le gusta menos o mas?            
Gaseosas                         Que marca le gusta?              
Gaseosas                         Le gusta la opcion 3 o 4?        
Gaseosas                         Cual es su sabor favorito        
Lacteos                          Le gusta la opcion 1 o 2?        
Lacteos                          Le gusta menos o mas?            
Lacteos                          Que marca le gusta?              
Lacteos                          Le gusta la opcion 3 o 4?        
Lacteos                          Cual es su sabor favorito        
Harinas                          Le gusta la opcion 1 o 2?        
Harinas                          Le gusta menos o mas?            
Harinas                          Que marca le gusta?              
Harinas                          Le gusta la opcion 3 o 4?        
Harinas                          Cual es su sabor favorito        
(25 rows)Execution time: 0.029 seconds
```

Si agregamos un criterio que nos pueda relacionar ambas tablas seria lo ideal. Por ejemplo:

```
select nombre, pregunta
from productos, preguntas
where id_producto = id_pregunta
```

Nos devuelve:

```
nombre                           pregunta                         
-------------------------------- -------------------------------- 
Cervezas                         Le gusta la opcion 1 o 2?        
Pañales                          Le gusta menos o mas?            
Gaseosas                         Que marca le gusta?              
Lacteos                          Le gusta la opcion 3 o 4?        
Harinas                          Cual es su sabor favorito        
(5 rows)Execution time: 0.037 seconds
```

Ahora hacemos uso de una instrucción [select into](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) para crear una nueva tabla a partir de estas columnas:

```
select nombre, pregunta
into productos_preguntas
from productos, preguntas
where id_producto = id_pregunta

select *
from productos_preguntas
```

Y tenemos nuestros datos:

```
nombre                           pregunta                         
-------------------------------- -------------------------------- 
Cervezas                         Le gusta la opcion 1 o 2?        
Pañales                          Le gusta menos o mas?            
Gaseosas                         Que marca le gusta?              
Lacteos                          Le gusta la opcion 3 o 4?        
Harinas                          Cual es su sabor favorito        
(5 rows)Execution time: 0.033 seconds
```

Si no importa que los datos se repitan puedes ignorar el criterio y dejarlo así:

```
select nombre, pregunta
into productos_preguntas
from productos, preguntas
```

Comment: Te refieres al **producto cartesiano**. El _plano cartesiano_ es otra cosa.

Comment: @jachguate no me había dado cuenta, gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias. La verdad y cierto si alguien tiene otra forma, se lo agradecere.